# Filter by first name OR last name using django-filter

Tags: python, django-filter

I need to search for users table filtering by first name or last name.

Given a user John Doe Smith, where John is the First Name and Doe Smith is the Last Name.

When I search for John Smith, it should find the user above.

I know that its just a matter of implementing the solution of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681708/querying-full-name-in-django/17361729#17361729), but how I do that in `django-filter` and keep other Filter Fields like `email` or `phone` also ?

`patient.py` (Only the relevant part)

```
class Patient(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField('Phone', max_length=14)
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What is your model?

Comment: Ah, just discovered the `method` parameter for the FilterSet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found out that `method` parameter is what I was looking for [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205851/how-to-search-from-many-fields/44211151#44211151)

Basically my code ended like this:

```
class PatientFilter(FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    last_name = CharFilter(name='last_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    phone = CharFilter(name='phone', lookup_expr='icontains')
    full_name = CharFilter(name='full_name', method='search_by_full_name')

    def search_by_full_name(self, qs, name, value):
        for term in value.split():
            qs = qs.filter(Q(name__icontains=term) | Q(last_name__icontains=term))
        return qs

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'phone']
```